# A longtext behaving as a text in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm sending a string of length 632768 characters in a webservice, and this string will be inserted in a field of type 'long text', that's supposed to fit in that type of text, but it's being truncated and it's just inserting 65535

[image: it's truncated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use fiddler to inspect what is going on on the air. Are you transferring 632768 bytes or 65535?

after that debug your back-end or at least put log to see incoming packet length or property value length.

check your back-end parameter DataType not the column data-type. If your parameter data-type is Text but you are inserting into LongText, your data get truncated before insert.

And then you may look MySQl side.

```
TEXT has 65,535 bytes ~64kb
LONGTEXT has 4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB
```

Comment: I'm just sending 632768 characters from the frontend and in the webservice it's being truncated

Comment: before inserting to mysql? what is your back-end?

Comment: I'm converting a image into base64 string and this string is of length more than 632768 characters.

Comment: sorry man my fault  `PROCEDURE `subirImage`(IN data TEXT)` it should be LONGTEXT

Comment: Yep as I expected. Goodluck! Btw If you think that my answer is useful for you please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer. thank you